# Chopper amplifier - working principle

Tags: amplifier, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, signal-processing

[This](http://course.ee.ust.hk/elec692w/lecture3_noise.pdf) lecture (page 59) shows how chooper amplifier works.

What I am confused is about the signal m2(t). It is delayed a time Δt. What is the purpose of this delay and how it effects the output Vout?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: [This EEVBlog video about Chopper Amplifiers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oibJUt6QkwI) is probably quite enlightening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The demodulation signal is delayed to match the delay in the amplifier- so the edges of the amplified modulated signal line up with the demodulation signal. Otherwise you won't get all the signal.